# How to configure ShrewSoft VPN to connect to Cisco VPN Server? continue

Tags: windows-8, vpn

I got "gateway authentication error" after I tried to connect to VPN, it also says that tunnel disabled, can it be the reason why I am not able to connect?

this is follow up question after answering topic with title:

How to configure ShrewSoft VPN to connect to Cisco VPN Server?

Comment: I imagine more detail will be needed before anyone will be able to help you much. What configuration do you have currently?

Answer (score 0):

You need an exception in the firewall policy of the server you're trying to connect to. Also, the ShrewSoft client needs to be configured correctly to talk to the firewall. Fortunately, most firewalls can generate a file (*.vpn file) you need that you can upload to the ShrewSoft client.